# How can I specify the number of decimal places with NumberFormat in Java?

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, string.format

Let's run this code :

```
double number = 12345.678888;
String str1 = String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%.10f", number);
String str2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(number);

System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
```

The outputs will be:

> 12345,6788880000
>
> 12 345,679

But those aren't what I want. I want to specify the number of decimal places with `NumberFormat` just like `String.format()` can do. I also tried `DecimalFormat` as well but I don't think that's the answer.

If I was writing C# code, it could be done simply like this :

```
string str = string.Format(new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), "{0:#,##0.0000000000}", number);
```

And the output would be:

> 12 345,6788880000

How can I achieve the same thing in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to the documentation, `NumberFormat` has [`setMaximumFractionDigits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits-int-) and [`setMinimumFractionDigits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-), so:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(10);
String str2 = formatter.format(number);
```

That gives me

```
12 345,6788880000
```

Comment: Just as expected! Thanks a million! :)

Comment: Can you do that on a single line though?

Comment: @Zach - I don't know. I don't immediately see a way in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html), but I don't do Java work virtually ever anymore so could be missing something.